# Turn on location services without navigating to settings page

Tags: android, location

Against the traditional approach of prompting user to go to the settings page and enable location services and come back again, I have noticed a simpler way of doing the same in some of the latest apps.

Referring to below screenshot, it prompts a dialog to user to enable the location services with just one click and it works in those apps.

How can I achieve the same?

[image]

Comment: Can negative voter(s) provide the reason?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. Up voted

Comment: @GAMA This is how the stackoverflow works! People don't need a reason to down vote. Such a hostile and great community at the same time!

Comment: @GAMA Only one downvote at all. :)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This dialog is created by [LocationSettingsRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest.Builder.html) available in the Google Play Services.

You need to add a dependency to your app `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```

Then you can use this minimal example:

```
private void displayLocationSettingsRequest(Context context) {
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings ");

                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                        // in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can find the complete example [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/8163f9f91bbb1ca6ed6470f5458b7c6c7e6f7ef7/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java).

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understood the first two lines: `You need to add a dependency to your app build.gradle:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`

Comment: You can find more information on how to settings up Google Play Service [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: where is **build.gradle** located?

Comment: Inside your application module directory. Usually the directory name is `app`

Comment: I couldn't find it. I'm using Eclipse (not Android studio).

Comment: You can find the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup under *ECLIPSE WITH ADT* section.

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini your link is broken

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini Thanks for the spam when I click on the page given in the link.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce I don't know where you see the spam. There are two link in the answer, one to github.com and the other one to developer.android.com. Either sources are official, reliable, and without spam.

Comment: Ignore that. I am so sorry. I had two tabs open on the same topic and someone gave a spammy link.

Comment: SettingsApi is now depricated.

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini can you please provide the full project please

Comment: android Q not working location on but return onActivityResult result `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`
but location turned on in phone

Comment: Can I somehow change the text in that dialog?

Comment: Since LocationServices.SettingsApi is deprecated. USE THIS:

SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

Answer (score 34):

## Follow the steps mentioned below

**1)** Create a `LocationRequest` as per your wish

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
           .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
           .setInterval(10 * 1000)
           .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
```

**2)** Create a `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder`

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder settingsBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
               .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
settingsBuilder.setAlwaysShow(true);
```

**3)** Get `LocationSettingsResponse` `Task` using following code

```
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
              .checkLocationSettings(settingsBuilder.build());
```

**Note:** `LocationServices.SettingsApi` is deprecated so, use `SettingsClient` Instead.

**4)** Add a `OnCompleteListener` to get the result from the Task.When the `Task` completes, the client can check the location settings by looking at the status code from the `LocationSettingsResponse` object.

```
result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
    try {
        LocationSettingsResponse response = 
                          task.getResult(ApiException.class);
        } catch (ApiException ex) {
            switch (ex.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = 
                                 (ResolvableApiException) ex;
                            resolvableApiException
                                   .startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, 
                                         LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**CASE 1:** `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` : Location is not enabled but, we can ask the user to enable the location by prompting him to turn on the location with the dialog (by calling `startResolutionForResult`).

[image: Google Map Location Settings Request]

**CASE 2:** `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE` : Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.

**5)** `OnActivityResult` we can get the user action in the location settings dialog. `RESULT_OK` => User turned on the Location. `RESULT_CANCELLED` - User declined the location setting request.

Comment: Where did you get the LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST?

Comment: @hayasiiiint, it is a local constant. It later should be used in `OnActivityResult`. See, for instance, *Ketan Ramani* answer here or https://github.com/android/location-samples/blob/8163f9f91bbb1ca6ed6470f5458b7c6c7e6f7ef7/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java.

Answer (score 14):

**Its Working Similar to google maps**

**Add Dependency in build.gradle file**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

this or that

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```

[image]

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;

import java.util.List;

public class LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static final String TAG = "LocationOnOff";

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);

        // Todo Location Already on  ... start
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && hasGPSDevice(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this,"Gps already enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        // Todo Location Already on  ... end

        if(!hasGPSDevice(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this)){
            Toast.makeText(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this,"Gps not Supported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && hasGPSDevice(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this)) {
            Log.e("keshav","Gps already enabled");
            Toast.makeText(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this,"Gps not enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            enableLoc();
        }else{
            Log.e("keshav","Gps already enabled");
            Toast.makeText(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this,"Gps already enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private boolean hasGPSDevice(Context context) {
        final LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (mgr == null)
            return false;
        final List<String> providers = mgr.getAllProviders();
        if (providers == null)
            return false;
        return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    private void enableLoc() {

        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            googleApiClient.connect();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                            Log.d("Location error","Location error " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
                        }
                    }).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                status.startResolutionForResult(LocationOnOff_Similar_To_Google_Maps.this, REQUEST_LOCATION);

                                finish();
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: SettingsApi is now depricated

Comment: SettingsApi is now deprecated. Now use SettingsClient: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient

Answer (score 14):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

**Variable Declaration**

```
private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 214;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_GPS = 516;
```

**Open Dialog Using Below Code**

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
builder.addLocationRequest(new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY));
builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(YourActivity.this);

mSettingsClient
    .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            //Success Perform Task Here
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
            switch (statusCode) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        rae.startResolutionForResult(YourActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                        Log.e("GPS","Unable to execute request.");
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.e("GPS","Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings.");
            }
        }
    })
    .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCanceled() {
            Log.e("GPS","checkLocationSettings -> onCanceled");
        }
    });
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                //Success Perform Task Here
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Log.e("GPS","User denied to access location");
                openGpsEnableSetting();
                break;
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_GPS) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGpsEnabled) {
            openGpsEnableSetting();
        } else {
            navigateToUser();
        }
    }
}

private void openGpsEnableSetting() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_GPS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If you use this code in fragment, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579124/2914140: instead of `rae.startResolutionForResult(activity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)` call `startIntentSenderForResult(rae.getResolution().getIntentSender(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS, null, 0, 0, 0, null)`, otherwise `onActivityResult()` won't be called.

Comment: @CoolMind Thanks may be use for someone who need this for fragment

Comment: @CoolMind, is it possible to use something similar to `startIntentSenderForResult` in the method `openGpsEnableSetting()`?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira, could you describe in details? In the code `openGpsEnableSetting()` simply starts a dialog to enable GPS settings. After it finishes, `onActivityResult()` is called with `requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_GPS`.

Comment: `onActivityResult()` is called from Activity and I was wondering if it is possible to return the result to the `Fragment` like `startIntentSenderForResult`.

Comment: @AlitonOliveira, see a new answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65816646/2914140.

Comment: @AlitonOliveira: It's not a new answer. It's in Kotlin. But, Thanks for sharing such links might be useful to some other :)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Mattia Maestrini **+1**

### Xamarin solution:

```
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Location;

public const int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

private void DisplayLocationSettingsRequest()
{
    var googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).AddApi(LocationServices.API).Build();
    googleApiClient.Connect();

    var locationRequest = LocationRequest.Create();
    locationRequest.SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy);
    locationRequest.SetInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.SetFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

    var builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().AddLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.SetAlwaysShow(true);

    var result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.CheckLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.Build());
    result.SetResultCallback((LocationSettingsResult callback) =>
    {
        switch (callback.Status.StatusCode)
        {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.Success:
                {
                    DoStuffWithLocation();
                    break;
                }
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.ResolutionRequired:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                        // in onActivityResult().
                        callback.Status.StartResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    }
                    catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
                    {
                    }

                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    // If all else fails, take the user to the android location settings
                    StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings));
                    break;
                }
        }
    });
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            {
                switch (resultCode)
                {
                    case Android.App.Result.Ok:
                        {
                            DoStuffWithLocation();
                            break;
                        }
                    case Android.App.Result.Canceled:
                        {
                            //No location
                            break;
                        }
                }
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

### **NOTE:**

This will not work with Huawei or other devices which does not have google services installed.

Comment: Its not working!! Can you please share complete code

Comment: I'm trying to call DisplayLocationSettingsRequest() method from OnCreate method of Android Activity. But unfortunately I'm not able to view the locationsettingrequest pop up which turns on Location. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @Omkar did you install the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location via Nuget? Did you include the two lines above `using 
android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Location;` ? After calling `LocationServices.SettingsApi.CheckLocationSettings` do you get a Callback within `result.SetResultCallback(` ? Place a break point at each of those and check what the code is doing

Comment: Yes I added all the prerequisites. And I received result as Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = (null). But this waiting time is infinite as waited for long time, and received no result.

Answer (score 6):

**Kotlin Solution**

Add `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

after that create this function

```
fun enablegps() {

    val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(2000)
        .setFastestInterval(1000)

    val settingsBuilder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
    settingsBuilder.setAlwaysShow(true)

    val result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(settingsBuilder.build())
    result.addOnCompleteListener { task ->

        //getting the status code from exception
        try {
            task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        } catch (ex: ApiException) {

            when (ex.statusCode) {

                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> try {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"GPS IS OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().
                    val resolvableApiException = ex as ResolvableApiException
                    resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                    )
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"PendingIntent unable to execute request.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Something is wrong in your GPS",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                }


            }
        }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Android Marshmallow 6 supports runtime permission. Runtime permissions only work on Marshmallow and on pre-Marshmallow it still works the old way.

You can learn more about it in this Android Developer official Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8lUdPVSzDk

And requesting permission: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Is Marshmallow API's available for development purpose?

Comment: so does that mean workflow shown through screenshot can only be achieved Marshmallow and later?

Comment: Yes, as stated in documentation it's API level 23 so it will only work on Marshmallow and newer.

Comment: any way to achieve the same behaviour in my own custom dialog

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Mattia Maestrini for the Answer, I would like to add that using

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'`

would suffice. This prevents your app including unnecessary libraries and helps for keeping your method count low.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace deprecated `onActivityResult` and `startResolutionForResult` in `Fragment`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65816646/2914140.

```
val checkLocationSettings = 
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // GPS is turned on in system settings.
        }
}

...

val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(resolvable.resolution).build()
checkLocationSettings.launch(intentSenderRequest)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void openDeviceLocationRequest() {
        if (!locationPermissionGranted)
            return;

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result =
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        result.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            try {
                LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.
                if(lastKnownLocation == null)
                getDeviceLocation();

            } catch (ApiException exception) {
                switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                        // user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                    MapAddressActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                            // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With recent Marshmallow update, even when the Location setting is turned on, your app will require to explicitly ask for permission. The recommended way to do this is to show the Permissions section of your app wherein the user can toggle the permission as required. The code snippet for doing this is as below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {     
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {     
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Permission");
        builder.setMessage("The app needs location permissions. Please grant this permission to continue using the features of the app.");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);     
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
        builder.show();
    }
} else {
    // do programatically as show in the other answer 
}
```

And override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Another approach is you can also use the [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) to inquire which location provider(s) are enabled. If none is enabled, you can prompt a dialog to change the setting from within the app.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found while my research, is to create a Util class for this location requesting process and then call it to turn the gps ON for us.

[Please check this blog!](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-turn-on-gps-programmatically-d585cf29c1ef) It told the whole story.

Comment: Downvoted because links can die, please add the solution on SO for future-proofness

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );        

    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
}
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    builder.setMessage( "Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?" )
            .setCancelable( false )
            .setPositiveButton( "Yes", (dialog, id) -> startActivity( new Intent( android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS ) ) )
            .setNegativeButton( "No", (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel() );
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```