# Auto active/deactive Location & Data

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-location

I've successfully developed a tracking app which logs the location of the mobile to a web server. But I have to keep active the location & data services all the time. Is there a way to enable and disable these services automatically, only when it requires.

Target version: Android 4.4.4 (KitKat)

Comment: refer this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page

Comment: That @OmDave is saying is the same as me when I refer to control the location inside the app with Google Play Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the data, there is nothing you can do. You can't enable/disable data connectivity (cellullar) programatically.

Regarding the location, you can't enable on demand, but you can open the settings location tab:
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

Or you can prompt to enable (not to disable) the location settings, just from inside of the app, showing a dialog with the help of Google Play Services. The docs are [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html)