# Is GPS activated - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to find out in Flutter if the GPS is activated or deactivated?
I use the plugin [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) however there I get only the location and not the state of the GPS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2019/10/25**

The location package now has a function (`serviceEnabled()`) to detect whether the location service is enabled and returns a bool as described in its [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-) and shown in the [example](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart):

```
bool serviceStatus = await _locationService.serviceEnabled();
if (service) {
    // service enabled
} else {
    // service not enabled, restricted or permission denied
}
```

**Old answer (package outdated)**

With [geolocations](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocation) you can check wether the location service is operational. It generally includes more customizability then the location package.

```
final GeolocationResult result = await Geolocation.isLocationOperational();
if(result.isSuccessful) { 
    // location service is enabled, and location permission is granted 
} else { 
    // location service is not enabled, restricted, or location permission is denied 
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocation       DART 2 INCOMPATIBLE with geolocation 0.2.1

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan thanks for mentioning. I updated the answer to use the latest location package as initially wanted by the OP.

Answer (score 22):

##### Update: (Geolocator 8.0.1)

```dart
bool isLocationEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
```

---

**Previous solution:**

Accepted answer uses outdated plugin, you can use [Geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) plugin,

```
var geoLocator = Geolocator();
var status = await geoLocator.checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();

if (status == GeolocationStatus.denied) 
  // Take user to permission settings
else if (status == GeolocationStatus.disabled) 
  // Take user to location page
else if (status == GeolocationStatus.restricted) 
  // Restricted
else if (status == GeolocationStatus.unknown) 
  // Unknown
else if (status == GeolocationStatus.granted) 
  // Permission granted and location enabled
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you display the activation dialog?

Comment: I am looking for the dialog box also. But seems like flutter does not provide it with any function.

Comment: @mik you will have to do that natively, this is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33254073/6618622) for Android.

Comment: @Yunus You will have to do it natively, see above link.

Comment: This library helps navigate to system settings https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings

Comment: @RajYadav You don't even need special library to open settings, `geolocator` does that for you

Answer (score 20):

Using the latest version of [Geolocator 5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

```
var isGpsEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();
```

I use this method to check and enable the Gps if disabled.

```
  Future _checkGps() async {
    if (!(await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled())) {
      if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Can't get gurrent location"),
              content:
                  const Text('Please make sure you enable GPS and try again'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Ok'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                        action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS');

                    intent.launch();
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This comment saved me. Those who are wondering, AndroidIntent() is from package called android_intent.

Comment: Wow, you guys are unexpectedly helpful. Thanks a bunch for AndroidIntent too.

Comment: iPhone doesn't have this case.

Comment: with this one package and one line of code you can open location settings in both platforms. 
AppSettings.openLocationSettings().       https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings

Answer (score 0):

Use catchError method with Geolocator, you don't have to use location pub

```
await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        // show location
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@humazed thanks for your answer, it's a modification of @humazed's answer with null-safety and Dart 3

**Pub:**
[Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and [AndroidIntent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus)

```
// Check the GPS is on
  Future _checkGps() async {
    if (!(await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled())) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text("Can't get current location"),
              content:
                  const Text('Your GPS is turn off, please turn it on first.'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('Turn On'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    const AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                        action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS');

                    await intent.launch();
                    if (!mounted) return;
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
checkLocationPermission() async {
final status = await Permission.location.request();
if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
  debugPrint('Permission granted');
  bool isLocationEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (isLocationEnabled) {
  // location service is enabled,
  } else {
  // open Location settings
    await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
  }
} else if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  debugPrint(
      'Permission denied. Show a dialog and again ask for the permission');
} else if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
  debugPrint('Take the user to the settings page.');
  await openAppSettings();
}
}
```