# Take user to device settings to active gps in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with gps management in a flutter application.

I've seen in this answer:

[Is GPS activated - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097428/is-gps-activated-flutter)

how I can check if a gps is active in a flutter app.

If is not active (GeolocationStatus.denied) how can I take with flutter a user to device settings for turn on gps?

Thank you.

Comment: Check https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler

Comment: Use above plugin and try "bool isShown = await PermissionHandler().shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PermissionGroup.contacts);". I don't enough time to check. try and let me know.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari didn't work :(

Comment: Check answer it is working in my device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable location tracking permissions from app itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787755/how-to-enable-location-tracking-permissions-from-app-itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install plugin :

> https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent#-installing-tab-

Import in your dart :

```
import 'package:android_intent/android_intent.dart';
```

Add method :

```
void openLocationSetting() async {
    final AndroidIntent intent = new AndroidIntent(
      action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS',
    );
    await intent.launch();
  }
```

Invoke it done...

Comment: This answer works great. But one issue i am facing once user enabled the GPS how can i run some function after that. Is there any way to it.