# In flutter how i can check if location is enabled?

Tags: flutter

I have problem when user entered google map page without location enabled the map wont updated so i want to check if the user have location enabled  beforehand so i need function  that return true if location enabled  and false if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [permission handler plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler) and then use it:

```
final PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
                .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
```

Comment: Does it check if the gps is operational and not if the app have location permission?

Comment: Checks @CopsOnRoad answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097428/is-gps-activated-flutter

Comment: It just checks for permission location but not GPS service

Answer (score 16):

use [permission handler plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

```
ServiceStatus serviceStatus = await PermissionHandler().checkServiceStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
bool enabled = (serviceStatus == ServiceStatus.enabled);
```

you can also show a rationale for requesting permission (Android only)

```
bool isShown = await PermissionHandler().shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PermissionGroup.location);
```

or [Location Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

```
var location = Location();
bool enabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
```

and request to enable it by

```
bool gotEnabled = await location.requestService();
```

Answer (score 12):

for those who came to this stackoverflow question like myself, there have been changes and updates on [PermissionHandler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package and the older solutions are now invalid.

you can check if the location service is enabled:

```
if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus.isEnabled) {
  // Use location.
}
```