# In flutter how i can check if location is enabled for IOS?

Tags: flutter, dart

I found solution for android in this post:

[In flutter how i can check if location is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059863/in-flutter-how-i-can-check-if-location-is-enabled)

but I still can not find how to check if location is enabled for IOS, I need to have bool, and I need to see if permision is granted, but is location off

Comment: the link you've provided have answer for both iOS and android. So, please check that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a package that can check the status of various permissions on Android & iOS

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check if location is enabled or not, and ask for permission if it is not enabled, this works with the [Geolocator package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/install) for both android and iOS

```
static Future<Position> getCurrentLocation(BuildContext context) async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Location services are disabled')));
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Location permission denied')),
        );
        Future.error('Location permission denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
            content: Text(
          'Location permission are permanently denied, kindly enable location permissions in your settings',
        )),
      );
      return Future.error(
          'Location permission are permanently denied, kindly enable location permissions in your settings');
    }
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

    return position;
  }
```