# Flutter - How to enable location service automatically in android?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am working on display near stores based on device location.I have enable the permission but unable to turn the location on.

How to enable location service automatically whenever i entered into my application if in off mode.

Whether it can achieved by write a platform channel to enable location on?

Comment: You can not enable it automatically. You should prompt a message then user will turn it on. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page/33254073

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @a.toraby What is the flutter equivalent of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page/33254073 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but in Android, you can't turn on the location via code. You can show user a [System Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page/33254073) and allow them to enable it.

Even Google maps can't turn on location off and on by itself. It asks user to do so.

PS: I don't know about iOS, but I think there also you can't turn on/off by yourself.

Comment: Ok fine. It's possible to enable location automatically in android older version like android 5.0?

Comment: @user9274318 I don't know that, but I think you can't.

Comment: could you please tell me whether System Dialog will works on older version before android 6.0. Its works fine in later version i.e., from android 6.0

Comment: When you run the same code in devices running Android  6.0 and lower what does it do/show?

Comment: I think it won't display system dialog less than Android 6.0 devices.

Comment: You can try searching for a solution on the internet regarding that.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad What is the flutter equivalend of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page/33254073 ? I asked a question here please assist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397823/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page-flutter-dart

Comment: @TSR I can definitely help you but right now I am out of office, once I get back there, I will answer yours in case no one had answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for native dialog window [Location plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

Example:

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';

var location = Location();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _checkGps();
}


Future _checkGps() async {
if(!await location.serviceEnabled()){
   location.requestService();
  }
}
```