# Turn on location services without navigating to settings page ? Flutter Dart

Tags: dart, geolocation, flutter, location

We are migrating from to Flutter. We used this thread to [Turn on location services without navigating to settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

How can this be achieved in Flutter?

The current temporary code that navigates to settings:

```
  Future _getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position;
    try {
      position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
    } on PlatformException catch(e){
      print(e.code);
      if(e.code =='PERMISSION_DISABLED'){
        print('Opening settings');
        await openLocationSetting();
        try {
          position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
        } on PlatformException catch(e){
          print(e.code);
        }
      }
    }

    setState(() {
//      _center = LatLng(currentLocation['latitude'], currentLocation['longitude']);
      _center = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    });
  }
  Future openLocationSetting() async {
    final AndroidIntent intent = new AndroidIntent(
      action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS',
    );
    await intent.launch();

  }
```

Comment: Check out the [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions) package.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can use the [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) package, you just have to add the required permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist files, permission will be asked in a pop-up.

Comment: enabling Location Permissions and Locations Services are 2 different things

Answer (score 0):

Add a map in the body of your screen

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
                rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
                mapToolbarEnabled: true,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                onTap: _placeMarker,
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                markers: Set.from(myMarker),
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 5.0,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: (EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 40)),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 30,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            navigate(context);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.done,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 30,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: **getLocation**,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.location_on,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: (EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 40)),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 30,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.chevron_left,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }


  getLocation() async {
    position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 36)));
  }
```

This code will initialize the Google maps in the home screen and if the location is turned of then an alert box will be popped up asking for the permission then it will be automatically turned on